# web api from inmemorydatabase to localdb

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm developing my first web api and started with an InMemoryDatabase on my Startup.cs file.

To move to a local db I updated my appsettings.json with the connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ArmariosPorMedidaContext":"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ArmariosPorMedidaContext;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

I updated my configure services method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ArmariosPorMedidaContext>(options => 
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ArmariosPorMedidaContext)));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }
```

Ran the following commands:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef update database
dotnet run
```

I get no errors and everything seems to work but upon opening the localhost page I now get a 404 error that wasn't happening before this.

Am I doing something wrong or did I forget anything?

Comment: check once your connection with database successfully established or not?

Comment: **404** means the server is not start or the address could not be found. Check whether you run launch your project.